# How to resize the image pixels in xamarin forms

Tags: image, xamarin.forms

My actual Image is

[image]

Here I need to resize the image 140*80(Width*height)

But after resize the circle in the image becomes oval how to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

Your current image resolution is **700*312** has a ratio of *1:2.2435897435897435897435897435897..*

The resolution you are trying to get is **140*80** has a ratio of *1:1.75*.

In order to get a perfect circle, you must maintain the same ratio between the images.

If acceptable, try resizing your image to **140*62.4** *(`62.4 = 140/(700/312)`)*.

More info about *Aspect Ratio* on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image)) .

Specifically for Xamarin, please show us what components are you using, or some example code so answers could be more specific.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Have you tried resizing the image to 140*62.4?

Comment: yes i have tried that .but it results the same image(circle becomes oval)

Comment: Please add a screenshot and a code snip of how you do it.